# Change the pixel to dp and set to the width of progress is error?

Tags: android, progress-bar, pixel

I set the width to `200dp` like the following code in `xml file`.

```
<ProgressBar 
                android:id="@+id/download_progress"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>
```

I try to change the width of `progressbar` in `JAVA file` like the following code.

```
float widthpx =  metrics.widthPixels;
float scale = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float width-dp = (widthpx/scale + 0.5f);
download_progress.getLayoutParams().width = (int) width-dp;
download_progress.invalidate();
```

And the `width-dp` is `360`.

When I didn't write the code in JAVA file , the width of progress is `200dp`.
And the the `width-dp` is `360` when I write the above code in JAVA file .

But why the width of `progressbar` is `200dp` is longer than `360` ?

Comment: **width-dp** will give you an error. try **width_dp**

Answer (score 2):

replace progress bar property.

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:progress="1" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work , I set getLayoutParams().width = (int) width-dp;. it doesn't fill the width of screen ,